# How to pod Snapkit without Masonry

Tags: cocoapods, masonry, snapkit

If you write `pod SnapKit` in your Podfile, another pod named `Masonry` will be also imported automatically.

Since my project is written only in the Swift language, how do I banish Masory from my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that [CCBottomRefreshControl](https://github.com/vlasov/CCBottomRefreshControl) relies on `Masonry`, so Masonry is imported with the former. @orta, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's from SnapKit? It's [Podspec](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit/blob/develop/SnapKit.podspec) does not mention that it relies on Masonry - so I'd be surprised if it comes from there .

Comment: I'm sure that my Podfile does NOT mention Masonry. However, it pods CCBottomRefreshControl, which relies on Masonry. Thank you for your promt.

Answer (score 1):

If the `CCBottomRefreshControl` relies on `Masonry`, you can not remove/banish `Masory` from your project.

I see the `CCBottomRefreshControl`; it's an OC Project… Maybe you can rewrite it.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to rewrite CCBottomRefreshControl using pure Swift without the help of SnapKit or Masonry.